# Align button in linear layout along with four textviews

Tags: android, android-layout

Creating a linear layout with 4 textviews and a button textviews are aligned one by one properly but below those textviews i am placing one button but it is aligning properly here I'm attaching screen

[image]

here button width i am giving wrap content then also text is not showing properly 
check this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="We are unable to process yoour request due to \n one of the following reasons: \n" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:text="1.The MOT test number does not exsist" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:text="The V5C document reference number \n does not exist or does not match the \n vehicle registration mark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: paste that pic or design which u want to make

Comment: see the above pic please in it text should display correctly text is ok button but i want to mention with as wrap content.

Comment: see my ans i send u button code which text in center

Answer (score 0):

Try this in button attribute-

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put everything inside a Linear Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="We are unable to process yoour request due to \n one of the following reasons: \n" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1.The MOT test number does not exsist" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="The V5C document reference number \n does not exist or does not match the \n vehicle registration mark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

## Please try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="We are unable to process yoour request due to \n one of the following reasons: \n" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="1.The MOT test number does not exsist" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="     The V5C document reference number \n     does not exist or does not match the \n     vehicle registration mark" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is eclipse issue just restarted my eclipse and my PC as well,Now alignment is good.It works.